# Can python nosetest and py.test frameworks run tests with multiprocessing

Tags: python-2.7, pytest, python-multiprocessing, nose

I have the following code that works fine when run as a python unittest but fails if using nosetest or py.test with the following error messages:

NoseTest error: 
*PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not found as teamcity.nose_report.newCaptureBeforeTest*

py.test error:
*PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not found as __builtin__.module*

Code:

```
import unittest
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

TIME_LIMIT = 1

class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.a = 0

    def my_func(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.q.put(self.a + 1)

    def run_case(self, func):
        self.q = mp.Queue()

        test_process = mp.Process(target=func)

        test_process.start()
        test_process.join(TIME_LIMIT)

        self.assertFalse(test_process.is_alive(), 'timeout exceeded')

    def test_case1(self):
        self.run_case(self.my_func)
        self.assertEquals(self.a + 1, self.q.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is avoided if the function under test is not in the same test class.  Not sure why but I believe the way py.test/nose are calling the parent class in order to fork the process is getting in a infinite loop.

```
import unittest
import multiprocessing as mp

TIME_LIMIT = 1

class Submission():
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = mp.Queue(1)

    def reset(self):
        while not self.score.empty():
            self.score.get()

    def run(self):
        self.score.put(0)

class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.func = Submission()
        self.a = 0

    def run_case(self):
        self.submission.reset()

        test_process = mp.Process(target=self.submission.run)
        test_process.start()
        test_process.join(TIME_LIMIT)

        self.assertFalse(test_process.is_alive(), 'timeout exceeded')
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_case1(self):
        self.run_case()
        score = self.submission.score.get()
        self.assertTrue(score >= self.a)
```